# VBA selenium get value

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

Hello I can't get some Values with selenium VBA

[image]

I am trying to get here the status from "readonly".
I am able to get the Value"XXXXYYY" with:

```
FUC_CODE = GC.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='C33_W105_V106_zaet_etqdata_ext.zzfinal_code']").Value
```

Also from another I want to grab the "same" value "value readonly"

[image]

Second question:
How can I see whats inside of a variant/object/webelement
In my understanding I am grabbing everything inside this div with this code:

```
Set FUC_CODE = GC.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='C33_W105_V106_zaet_etqdata_ext.zzfinal_code']")
```

But how can i loop or earch through every element to find for example  .Value above
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: to get an attribute of an element you have captured use:

`aVariable = FUC_CODE.Attribute("readonly")`

where the attribute's name is in quotes, and the aVariable is variant or of an appropriate type.

Second question: there is no means to see the list of attributes without coding, using the above construction.